# generating functions at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am trying to generate functions at compile time using boost hana. Here is the code I wrote

```
#include <boost/hana/transform.hpp>

#include <array>

template<int i>
double f(double x)
{
    return x * i; 
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array arr = {1,5,10,100,500};

    constexpr auto functions = hana::transform(arr, 
        [](const int a) -> double (*)(double)
        {
            return f<a>;
        }
    );

}
```

when compiling I get the error that f is not convertible to type double (*)(double).

I think the problem is that a is not constexpr(which is not possible since it is a function argument). Is there a way to make this working?

Comment: No, there is no way to instantiate a template with a runtime value.

Comment: but the array is known at compile time...

Comment: Well it would be interesting if you wrote a `constexpr` function and used that instead of your lambda. That might work (I don't know how far constexpr is willing to introspect). Aslo is `hana::transform` constexpr? Probably not...

Comment: @galik - "That might work" - Have you tried? If the `a` value (the value used for `f<a>`) is passed through a template parameter, should works, `constexpr` or not `constexpr`. But if `a` is passed as normal parameter, shouldn't works, also inside a `constexpr` function, because a `constexpr` function can be called also run-time.

Comment: Also Lambdas can be constexpr so this makes no diffrence

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to make this working?

Not this way.

Look at your lambda

```
    [](const int a) -> double (*)(double)
    {
        return f<a>;
    }
```

You're using the argument `a`, that is potentially known run-time in a lambda, as template parameter, that **must** be known compile type.

Can't work.

Comment: @user3726947 - I don't see a way with `std::array`. Is good for you if you use `std::integer_sequence`; something as `std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 5, 10, 100, 500>`?